# Flutter setting children dynamically

Tags: android, dart, flutter

So I want to set the children of my GridView dynamically so I can set it when I want. Currently this is the whole class.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/CustomColors.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/quote/Quote.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/quote/QuoteView.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/section/Section.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/quote/QuoteData.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  static List<QuoteData> data = [];

  _readJson() async {
    data.clear();
    var url = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/7k280ca5dktlhoo/quotes.json?dl=1';
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url)).then((HttpClientRequest request) {
      return request.close();
    }).then((HttpClientResponse response) {
      response.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((contents) {
        List<Map> decoded = JSON.decode(contents);
        decoded.forEach((m) {
          String url = m["url"];
          String title = m["title"];
          String sectionString = m["section"];
          Section section;
          for (Section element in Section.values) {
            if (element.toString() == "Section." + sectionString) {
              section = element;
            }
          }
          List<Quote> quotes = m["quotes"];
          data.add(new QuoteData(url, title, section, quotes));
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _readJson();
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Quotes',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or press Run > Flutter Hot Reload in IntelliJ). Notice that the
        // counter didn't reset back to zero; the application is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: CustomColors.black,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Quotes'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  static Section currentSection = Section.movies;

  void _onTileClicked(QuoteData quote) {
    Navigator.push(context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new QuoteView(quote)));
  }

  List<Widget> _getTiles(Section section) {
    final List<Widget> tiles = <Widget>[];
    for (var i in MyApp.data) {
      if (i.section != section) {
        continue;
      }
      tiles.add(new GridTile(
          child: new InkResponse(
        enableFeedback: true,
        child: new Image.network(
          i.url,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        onTap: () => _onTileClicked(i),
      )));
    }
    return tiles;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double itemHeight = (size.height - kToolbarHeight - 24) / 2;
    final double itemWidth = size.width / 2;
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: new Text(currentSection
                .toString()
                .replaceAll("Section.", "")
                .substring(0, 1)
                .toUpperCase() +
            currentSection.toString().replaceAll("Section.", "").substring(1)),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: new GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            childAspectRatio: (itemWidth / itemHeight),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
            children: _getTiles(currentSection)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So right now on startup, it launches the application but MyApp.data is empty because the json has to be read so the GridView will be empty, when I refresh the application, the GridView won't be empty because MyApp.data won't be empty anymore. I want to be able to set the children after the json gets read, also I need to be able to change it dynamically because I will add a function for switching sections.

The same goes for the title, I also need to be able to change it dynamically  when switching sections.

Comment: You can use a https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html. If you have the values already you can return it using `new Future.value(myData)` or if you fetch or load the data from a method that is marked `async` you'll always get a `Future` back.

Comment: I'm not able to use FutureBuilder in a GridView

Comment: Why not? You can wrap your `GridView` in a `FutureBuilder`

Comment: Thanks I got that part, but I don't quite understand with what you mean with the last sentence, where you get a Future back in an async method.

Comment: I haven't tried `FutureBuilder` myself yet ( :D ), but I assume it expects a `Future`. If you fetch the data from the server, you'll have a `Future` automatically, but later when you have the data already and need it as `Future`, you can use `Future.value(data)`, but it's possible `FutureBuilder` doesn't care anyway and recognizes if it's a `Future` or not.

Comment: Future.value expects a FutureOr<T> value so when I put MyApp.data which is a list, it won't work. Currently I have this https://hastebin.com/upodojivam.cs

Comment: `FutureOr<T>` is exactly for accepting `T` (non-Future) or `Future<T>` which is a `Future`. What error do you get?

Comment: Future.value wants a FutureOr<T> but MyApp.data is a List<T> so I can't use it.

Comment: What is the error message you get? `T` is just a parameter name. Try `new Future<dynamic>.value(MyApp.data)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167868/discussion-between-emrage-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Sorry had to leave. What is the current status?

Comment: Got nothing further currently this is the code https://hastebin.com/opelewayus.scala on startup the debugPrint("Yes"); does get called but debugPrint("Yes 1"); doesn't. If I refresh the application both get called.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a loading widget and wait for the request to finish when the request is finished hide the loading and show the grid than rebuild the state. but you need to have a statefullWidget not statelessWidget.

You can see how i use it on the code below I added my comments to the code

```
class _ChildrenPageState extends State<ChildrenPage>  {
  //declare the _load to true so it will show the loading when the page is loaded
  bool _load = true;
  ChildrenService _childrenService = new ChildrenService();
  List children = [];

  //I call the _rebuild function to rebuild the widgets and show the data
  void _rebuild() {
    setState(() {
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //I call the request to get my data when it is finished i put _load to false so the loading will hide and call the _rebuild function to rebuild the widgets and i have put if so when the widget is built it will not rebuild it a second time.

    _childrenService.getChildren(children).then((data){
      if(data && _load){
        _load = false;
        _rebuild();
      }
    });

    //the below widget show the loading container if _load is true else it will show the dataTable in your app you should add the grid and you can pass the data that you got from the request

    Widget loadingIndicator = _load ? new Container(
      color: Colors.grey[300],
      width: 70.0,
      height: 70.0,
      child: new Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child: new Center(
              child: new CircularProgressIndicator()
          )
      ),
    ) : new JLDataTable(
      data: children,
    );

    return new Scaffold(
        drawer: new Drawer(
          child: MenuList.menuList,
        ),
        appBar: new AppBar(title: const Text('Data tables')),
        body: new ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            children: <Widget>[
                new Align(
                    child: loadingIndicator,
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.center
                )
            ]
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I have decided to stop using flutter. I might try it out again if you are able to access the views through code.